Is there any general rule for determining a suitable shift-length in an MC simulation?
I have written a program for MC simulation of LJ particles in NVT. I have used reduced units to run simulations.
Is there any general rule for determining a suitable shift length range?
By shift length, I mean the length added to the old position for generating a new position.
For instance,
shift_length = 1.25

# Generate random shifts for x, y, and z
dx = 1.0 - 2.0 * random.random()
dy = 1.0 - 2.0 * random.random()
dz = 1.0 - 2.0 * random.random()

# Update the coordinates
new_x = old_x + dx * shift_length
new_y = old_y + dy * shift_length
new_z = old_z + dz * shift_length


It is also known as:

Step Size
Displacement Length
Move Size
Perturbation Size
Maximum Displacement
etc.


The general rule is to determine it as the value that maximizes the efficiency of the MC simulation. Over the years, different efficiency measurements have been identified. For many years (and sometimes even now), a value such that the ratio between accepted and total moves is about 0.5 has been advised.
However, such a rule has no sound justification. Some studies have tried to connect the acceptance ratio with reasonable efficiency measurements. We could choose the maximum displacement by minimizing the energy variance or maximizing the mean square displacement of the particles. Both criteria for an LJ interaction provide similar values and correspond to values of the acceptance ratio smaller than 0.5.
Usually, values between 0.1 and 0.3 are optimal, although values up to 0.5 are acceptable, although sub-optimal.
References:
Talbot, J., Tarjus, G., & Viot, P. (2003). Optimum Monte Carlo simulations: some exact results. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, 36(34), 9009.
Kolafa, J. (1988). On optimization of Monte Carlo simulations. Molecular Physics, 63(4), 559–579.
